# nginx proxing not working properly

Tags: nginx

I have hosted different drupal sites in an Ubuntu server. Nginx is running as a webserver in this server.All sites are working fine. 
For security reasons i need to enable a Nginx proxy server ahead of the above server. Configured proxy. The following is the configuration file that i used for proxying . The result of this is when i access the url www.drupal.com it redirect to http://www.drupalsite.com.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  www.drupal.com;

  location / {

    proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header Connection Close;
    proxy_pass http://www.drupalsite.com;
    proxy_redirect  /    /;
  }
}
```

I don't need url redirection. i need the base url is www.drupal.com

Answer (score 0):

If 'nginx' is running on the same host as http://www.drupalsite.com, then you have conflict because they are both attempting to use port 80. If that's the issue, you need to move drupalsite.com to a new port or a new server.

Also, try removing "proxy_set_header" and "proxy_redirect" directives. They are not essential.

As always, check your access your access and error logs to see if they shed light on what's happening.

Comment: www.drupal.com and www.drupalsite.com is running in different server. So both are running on port 80 in different server.

Comment: Also, try removing "proxy_set_header" and "proxy_redirect" directives. They are not essential.